# Ubuntu Phone OS 1.0 makes my Galaxy Nexus a lame duck

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I am testing Ubuntu Phone OS since 2 months. In this time the speed and reaction of Phone OS increased by every update. Yesterday I made an update to 1.0 via phablet-flash ubuntu-system --no-backup . Now I have a phone OS that is incredible slow. Is this problem known? Are there any options to solve this speed problem? Looking for some answers. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is a known problem:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/mir/+bug/1182930

Unfortunately the Galaxy Nexus is starting to show its age, so certain operations that can run efficiently on newer hardware are problematic on the it.  Things may improve, but I don't know if there is a concrete time line.

As a temporary solution, you could try disabling Mir on the phone by deleting the file `/home/phablet/.display-mir` and rebooting, which will switch back to the Surface Flinger display server.  Note however that all future development is being done with Mir in mind, so this isn't guaranteed to continue working.